# can't install Net::Pcap module

Tags: perl, network-programming, perl-module, cpan

I am trying to install Net::pacp module ,I followed the below steps

1.$ perl Makefile.PL INC=-I/opt/pcap/include  LIBS='-L/opt/pcap/lib -lpcap'
which produces output as

```
looking for -lpcap... yes
checking for pcap_lib_version() in -lpcap... yes
detecting available functions... ok
Writing Makefile for Net::Pcap
```

2.$ make
this step is throwing an error as  `make: *** [Pcap.o] Error 1`

can anyone please help me with this

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Once go and check,if the module is available in `cpan.org` or not

Comment: I downloaded this module (Net::Pcap-0.17) from cpan.org

Comment: It was installed on one of my machine but couldn't on another one,Does it depend on perl version

Comment: In your current machine what is the version of Perl?

Comment: Which machine you are using?

Comment: the machine on which it installed has perl v5.12.2  ,on the machine i am trying to install has perl v5.10.1  ,I am also unable to install it on machine having higher version of perl v5.16.3

Comment: which OS you are using?

Comment: installed on fedoro 14 ,iam trying to install on scientific-linux6.3

Comment: `sudo yum install perl-Net-Pcap`

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing that you're using Linux. In which case you can probably just install the version that is pre-packaged for your distribution.

On Fedora/Centos/RHEL

```
$ sudo yum install perl-Net-Pcap
```

On Debian/Ubuntu

```
$ sudo apt-get install libnet-pcap-perl
```